# xbox sign in not working after deploying app in visual studio

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox-one, xbox-live

So while testing my scene and the ones provided by the Microsoft in Unity I properly get and sign into an xbox live user account (EX: FAKE USER 1) but when I bring my game to visual studio and deploy it to either my win10 device or my xbox one sandbox it stops signing me in right. I've been up and down Microsoft forums and documentation and nothing was of any help. I tried multi user and guest set up. I've tried changing my xboxservices.config file. I've tried hitting the test button on my Microsoft dev account. I tried signing in different accounts before attempting to open and use my game. That's just a few things I've tried.

[Xbox Sign in in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG3V9.jpg)

[Xbox Sign in in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gW0.jpg)

How do I go about figuring out where the sign in issue is?

EDIT: I finally got an exception error when testing the unity plugin example scene for multi user sign in.

```
onecoreuap\xbox\xblauth\tokenbrokerext\dll\xblauth.cpp(639)\XblAuthTokenBrokerExt.dll!00007FFCE2C570C5: (caller: 00007FFCE2C55E50) LogHr(1) tid(1bb4) 8015DC1E onecoreuap\xbox\xblauth\tokenbrokerext\dll\xblauth.cpp(375)\XblAuthTokenBrokerExt.dll!00007FFCE2C5609F: (caller: 00007FFCE2C55876) ReturnHr(1) tid(1bb4) 80070490 Element not found.
onecoreuap\xbox\xblauth\tokenbrokerext\dll\xblauth.cpp(639)\XblAuthTokenBrokerExt.dll!00007FFCE2C570C5: (caller: 00007FFCE2C55E50) LogHr(2) tid(1bb4) 8015DC12 onecoreuap\xbox\xblauth\tokenbrokerext\dll\xblauth.cpp(375)\XblAuthTokenBrokerExt.dll!00007FFCE2C5609F: (caller: 00007FFCE2C55876) ReturnHr(2) tid(1bb4) 80070490 Element not found.
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xbox.Services.XboxException' in Microsoft.Xbox.Services.UWP.CSharp.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Xbox.Services.XboxException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in Assembly-CSharp.dll
An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in Assembly-CSharp.dll but was not handled in user code
AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage
```

Comment: Please report it directly to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution: closing the session in the Xbox Live app.